# Gitlab-runner cannot access remote docker daemon in another VM

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to connect to a docker daemon running on a VM using `DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@IPAddress"`.
I have configured the machine using with correct ssh keys.

From the gitlab-runner VM I can manually login to the remote machine using `ssh user@IPAddress`. I accessing it under the `gitlab-runner` user account. gitlab-runner account is in the docker group. It is a non login account. Not added to the sudo group either. 
When I try to accesss docker daemon from a gitlab CI job with Shell executor.

```
Job:
  - echo "$(whoami)"
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_devops
  - export DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@IPAddress"
  - docker info
```

**Output**

```
gitlab-runner
Agent pid 7418
/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa_devops: No such file or directory
```

I checked the key, and it is there on that path.
I am not sure what is going wrong can someone tell me please ?

Comment: What is the file permission based on the output of `stat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_devops` ?

Comment: @Lukman Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (  999/gitlab-runner)   Gid: (  998/gitlab-runner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with the extra line after the `ssh-add` instruction and it worked.

`- ssh-keyscan <IPAddress here> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have implemented similar scenario (datacenter). There I created a gitlab-runner login account and once you have to log to remote server from it to make authenticity.

Comment: I have already done it. I wrote that I can login from the gitlab-runner machine to the remote machine using the key and account.